# Structuring files in a flask application not importing

Tags: python, flask, directory, structure

I am struggling with imports in my flask application.

This is the current structure I have

```
    app/
       __init__.py
       config.py
       db_create.py
       models.py
       views.py 
    run.py
```

In my `__init__.py` file I have the following code:

```
    from flask import Flask
    from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config')
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

    from app import views, models
```

In my `run.py` I have the following code:

```
    #!flask/bin/python
    from app import app
    app.run()
```

In `db_create.py` I have:

```
    from app import db
```

and the rest of my code creating the db and adding some sample data.

However, when I try and run `db_create.py` I get the following error:

```
    ImportError: No module named app
```

I am not sure what the problem here, if it is cyclical imports or another problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `app/__init__.py` you have:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

and

```
from app import views, models
```

So, `app` is both a package name and a `Flask` instance?

Don't give the same name to two things.

And place all of your imports at the top of the file, that will simplify your life at least a bit.

Comment: Okay, I will change the naming. Yes app is both a package name and a Flask instance. The reason those imports are after the app variable has been initialised is to avoid circular imports as views,models need the app variable initialised.

Comment: @Msa Well, you should avoid circular imports by *avoiding* circular imports ;) Everything needs to access `app` (the Flask instance), so it should be in a module (`app.py` is a good name, if you dont have `from app import ...` in it) which everyone can import. That means you should not import any other of your modules from `app.py`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem of structure in your application.
You can import app from `run.py`, but you should not import it from `app/db_create.py`. That is by fact a cyclic import. If you need something from the `app/__init__.py` file, export it to another .py file that you can import from `db_create.py`.

Answer (score 0):

This approach does not work because you don't have variable `app` inside the `db_create.py` .

See in `__init__.py`  you have initialized a variable called app. 
And now in `run.py` you import `app` variable from `app directory`.

Now since `db_create` and `__init__` are in the some directory you need to import like this `from __init__ import app`.

Although I would suggest that instead of creating a file `db_create.py`, use the same code in `__init__.py`, since you are doing this only for testing purpose.

Also in `__init__.py` use `import views, models` directly instead of `from app import views, models`
(since they are also in same directory)

Hope I was able to explain it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to find app.py to insert app object from it, but does not find it. If you set it as

```
"from __init__ import app"
```

will work, but this is also not a good practice.

If you are about to do micro app as flask is good at and you might have structure like:

```
app/
  app.py 
  app.cfg
  db_create.py
  models.py
```

Where all the Flask app initialization and routes are in the app.py.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from db_create import DbOperations

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('app.cfg')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db_operations = DbOperations(db)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    db_operations.create() #or something like this
....


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Then the big chunks of code are moved to classes out of the app.py like db_create.py:

```
class DbOperations:
         def create(self, db):
         ... some logic
```